# Apache jena: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, maven, jena

When I run the example from the docs(https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/): I get following error:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        String SOURCE = "http://www.eswc2006.org/technologies/ontology";
        String NS = SOURCE + "#";
        
        OntDocumentManager mgr = new OntDocumentManager();
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
        
        Model base = m.getBaseModel();
        
        String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/people.owl";
        OntDocumentManager dm = m.getDocumentManager();
        dm.addAltEntry( "http://www.eswc2006.org/technologies/ontology",
                        "file:" +path );
        
        Resource mass = m.createResource("http://somewhere/Testressource");
        mass.addProperty(VCARD.FN, "test");
        
        m.write(System.out);
        

}
```

I only have jena as a maven dependency

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>jena</groupId>
  <artifactId>jena-id</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
         <version>4.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a logging implementation to your application.

apache-jena-libs is a library; it uses slf4j as an API to abstract way from the choice of logging.

Example:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
```