# Unable to 'Maven Build' my Java Project in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a working Java Project (literally just 2 JAVA files) that need to be built in either Maven or Gradle. Since I wrote my Java Project in **Eclipse IDE for Java Delopers** (`Kepler Service Release 2`, `20140224-0627`), [I found this article to add Maven to my Java Project.](https://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/)

After adding Maven to my project, [I had to follow this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error/59781316#59781316) to allow myself to Right Click the Project -> `Maven` -> `Update Project...` properly. If I Right Click the Project -> `Run As` -> `Maven Clean`, I get a `BUILD SUCCESS` ([thanks to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732779/apache-jena-slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder/71737848#71737848)). But now when I Right Click the Project -> `Run As` -> `Maven Install`, I get the following:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AMC 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ RobTillmanProject ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Users\names\workspace\paging-mission-control\AMC\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ RobTillmanProject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\Users\names\workspace\paging-mission-control\AMC\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.050s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 07 16:35:15 EST 2023
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project RobTillmanProject: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

As per the error, it looks like I need to add a JDK to the `Installed JREs` list ([just as this SO answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21099229/19657086)).

In Eclipse IDE, `Windows` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Installed JREs`, I have `jre1.8.0_333 (default)` installed. On my PC, in my `C:\Program Files\Java` folder, I've installed `jdk-17`, `jdk-17.0.6` and `jdk-19.0.2`. However, when I go to add any one of the JDKs (I've tried JRE Type `Standard 1.1x VM` and `Standard VM`), I get the error message `Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found.`

I'm running Eclipse IDE on Windows 10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Eclipse Kepler SR2 is 9 years and 23 releases behind. Of course, it cannot recognize a Java 17 or 19 JDK released years after Eclipse Kepler. [Make sure to use the current version of Eclipse which is currently 2022-12](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Comment: @howlger I installed Eclipse `Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)`, `Build id: 20221201-1913`. I can now `Maven Install`. However, I am unable to `Maven Build`: https://ibb.co/17dm0dC (my first time with Maven, I have no idea what I need to do to make it buildable). I also receive this if I run `mvn -version` in cmd: https://ibb.co/smq4VJh

Comment: I should also mention: I've followed this guide https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-maven-windows and still getting the "'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error in cmd

Comment: Eclipse 2022-12 comes with an embedded Maven, so you don't need to install Maven into your system (but if you do, the guide you followed is misleading: the `PATH` has to be extended with the `bin` directory of your Maven installation, e.g. by adding something like `;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.0\bin` to the end). Your question is still about Kepler which is pretty outdated. Please fix this. [Please show also your `pom.xml` and your Maven run configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding the correct location for the JDK home in the "Installed JREs" section.

[image]

For instance, I am using JDK 8 and selecting the **JDK as the default** as below:

[image]

Make sure you are also changing the compiler version to use the one matching your JDK.  Other side, like your are using maven clean install to build your project, then make sure the maven distribution is using the correct JAVA_HOME.

In Eclipse, go to again Window / Preferences / Maven / **Installations**

Select your local maven distribution instead of using the embed version with Eclipse, for instance:

[image]

You can check if your maven distribution is using the correct JDK by typing in a cmd :  `mvn -version`, for example in my Windows I am using JDK 11 like you can see in the below output:

[image]

Hope this can help.  Please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for offering to help. Unfortunately, what you're suggesting hasn't helped. Here is the error I get when trying to add jdk-17.0: https://ibb.co/mCydkfr, and the error for trying to install `apache-maven-3.9.0`: https://ibb.co/PDyPvWD and then when I run `mvn -version`: https://ibb.co/smq4VJh . I unzipped `apache-maven-3.9.0` to my PC, so I'm not sure why "mvn" isn't recognized as installed.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am seeing the same issue on my Mac Eclipse install